# Close Window popup in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a website in java and must close a Window pop -up , the problem is that already tried using Selenium to close it and could not.

Is there any simple way to close it using JAVA ? No need to click anything, just need to close it even .

It does not work well:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("btnClose")).click();
```

[image: Window Popup]

I tried with this code and yet she does not close and shows error

```
String windowHandleJanelaInicial = driver.getWindowHandle();
        WebElement elementoQueAbreNovaJanela = driver.findElement(By.name("btnSimulateDK"));
        elementoQueAbreNovaJanela.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for(String windowHandle : handles) {        

            if( !windowHandle.equals(windowHandleJanelaInicial) ) {
                 driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
                driver.close();

            }
        }

        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandleJanelaInicial);
```

Comment: How would Java close this? Do you actually mean Javascript? In that case, it is window.close()

Comment: @ControlAltDel   I am using java to automate and need to close this screen , I can not use JavaScrip this project, or it is possible to mix the two languages?                   driver.findElement(By.name("btnSimulateDK")).click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Simply use close() to close a window. First switch to it (driver.switchTo.window(...)), then call driver.close(). You can locate elements that are part of the website only. The window close button is out of the website (if "btnClose" is actually part of the website, then does it work manually?). You can also use JS using ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.close();",""); after switching to this window to close it using JS.

Comment: @skandigraun would look like ? driver.switchTo().window("I put that here ?").close();

Comment: You only need to switch to that window if it is not the active already. If it is active already, simply call driver.close();. If it is not active, do something like  String originalHandle=driver.getWindowHandle(); for (String handle: driver.getWindowHandles()){if (!handle.equals(originalHandle){driver.switchTo.window(handle);}} And call driver.close() after that. (This works only for 2 windows. With more windows you need to determine on some other way which window you have to switch to)

Comment: @skandigraun I updated the question with the code used to close it, check out what I did wrong and let me know. Does not close the page and shows no error on the console.